# Massive and massless modes in the Klein-Gordon equation

Tags: causality, greens-functions, propagator, klein-gordon-equation

I am studying the massive Klein-Gordon equation in 3+1 dimensions with a given scalar source. The equation I am looking at is

$$
(\Box +m^2)\phi(x)=J(x) \ ,
$$

and am interested in the following question: considering a time-independent source, are there mass terms for the leading behaviour in $1/r$ of $\phi(x)$ at large distances? To answer the question, I first tried to express the solution as a convolution with a retarded Green function

$$
\phi(x)=\int d^4y J(y)G_{ret}(x-y) \ ,
$$

where

$$
G_{ret}(t,r)=
\frac{1}{4 \pi}\left[\frac{\delta\left(t-\frac{r}{c}\right)}{r}+\mu c \Theta(c t-r) \frac{J_{1}(\mu u)}{u}\right] \text { with } u=\sqrt{c^{2} t^{2}-r^{2}} \ .
$$

By looking at this expression, I would say that contributions to $\phi(x)$ that scales as
$1/r$ come only from the first term. Since these are related to massless modes, then there are no mass terms for the leading behaviour of $\phi(x)$ at $1/r$. Intuitively, this is like saying that mass terms only scales as $1/r^n$ for $n$ larger than one. However, I don't have a rigorous proof of this fact for arbitrary time-independent sources. Does my reasoning make sense/is it possible to prove this statement for all sources?

Comment: A massive scalar field decays as $e^{-mr}/r$, not as $1/r$.

Comment: That's also my intuition, but how can you prove it for any source? Also, I think you misunderstood me. I am not saying that a massive field scale as 1/r. I am asking what is the leading term in 1/r for a massive scalar and if it is mass independent.

Comment: What are you keeping fixed as you take $r \to \infty$?

Comment: t-r fixed, and r large

Comment: Massless fields reach ${\mathscr I}^+$, but massive fields do not. So I suspect the limit you are looking at will be messy. Let me think about it.

Comment: Actually, now that I am thinking about... the limit I am interest is t fixed and large r (I see your point about scri +)